# how to convert textfile with key value pairs to ordered output via unix commands

Tags: shell

I have a text file which contains for different variables the possible ranges of values

```
1. life:        short,long,na.
2. weather_f:   cloudy,rainy,sunny,foggy,cold,warm,mild,
                    humid,na.
3. sea_temp:    warm,mild,cold,na.
```

I would like to get an outputfile which looks like this

```
short,long,na
cloudy,rainy,sunny,foggy,cold,warm,mild,humid,na
warm,mild,cold,na
```

I tried to use `sed` for this but the new line in `weather_f` gives me a hard time. how can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a line ends with a comma, append the next line to the buffer immediately.  This is done in `sed` using the expression

```
/,$/N
```

The `N` command appends the next line to the text in the buffer, with a newline character as delimiter between the two.

To allow for more than a single such continued line, loop back to the start of the cycle to check whether there's a comma at the end of the buffer.

```
:again
/,$/ {
    N

    # branch to the "again" label at the top
    b again
}
```

After this, there is no more line that we need to append to the buffer, so we can start to trim the line down and arrange it in the way we want.  This includes deleting everything up to the first `:` character, deleting all space-like characters (including the newlines inserted by `N`), and chopping off the dot at the end.

```
s/[^:]*://
s/[[:space:]]//g
s/\.$//
```

The whole editing script would be

```
:again
/,$/ {
    N
    b again
}
s/[^:]*://
s/[[:space:]]//g
s/\.$//
```

This may be executed with the script in a file (here, `script`) like

```bsh
sed -f script file
```

or, if you want to type the script on the command line,

```bsh
sed -e :again \
    -e '/,$/ { N; b again; }' \
    -e 's/[^:]*://' \
    -e 's/[[:space:]]//g' \
    -e 's/\.$//' file
```

Given the data in your question, this would output

```
short,long,na
cloudy,rainy,sunny,foggy,cold,warm,mild,humid,na
warm,mild,cold,na
```

Some `sed` implementations may need `b again` to be its own expression:

```bsh
sed -e :again \
    -e '/,$/ { N' -e 'b again' -e '}' \
    -e 's/[^:]*://' \
    -e 's/[[:space:]]//g' \
    -e 's/\.$//' file
```